# Passing a form variable from HTML to Javascript, but with quotes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I'm trying to pass an email address from an HTML form into a javascript snippet to pass to another program.

Form input:

```
<input name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address Here" type="email" required="required" id="email_input">
```

Here's an example of what I'm looking for, note the quotes. **In order for the email to pass, it must be within quotes.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: "example@example.com", 

});
</script>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: "document.getElementById("email_input");", 

});
</script>
```

If I'm using a static value like example@example.com, everything works as expected. I'm not able to figure out how to pass the value from the email input field to the "email:" javascript and have it pass though.

Heres what I need: What I have in there **document.getElementById("email_input");** is not working, what should this be?

I'm know I'm missing something simple here, just not sure what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... It's not entirely clear what you need. If you just need a string value then leave out the surrounding quotes. If you explicitly need a json string then convert the object to json.

Comment: When should that 'test' function run? Is it in the same page as the input element?

Comment: You just need to pass the input value or you need to pass the input value like a string with quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to pass the value of the email input using that `test` object, this is what you need.

```
var emailString = document.getElementById("email_input").value;
test({

  email: emailString, 

});
</script>
```

You want to grab the value of the input first, and then pass it as a string (assuming you need a string from your first example)

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to get a string from an other typeof element (DOM element, Number, Array, ...) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elmt = document.getElementById("email_input");

    var str1 = elmt.toString();
    var str2 = elmt + "";
    // alert(str1); and alert(str2) will pop the same result : a string of elmt
</script>
```

so if you want the entire input as a string you should do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: document.getElementById("email_input") + '' 

});
</script>
```

if you just want the input value as a string (so the email) you should do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: document.getElementById("email_input").value + '' 

});
</script>
```

and if you really need to add quotes to a string you also can do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str= "this is my string";
    var withquote= ' " ' + str + ' " ';

    //both of the var return a string but one will have a quote and the other won't
    alert(str); // pop: this is my string
    alert(withquote); // pop "this is my string"
</script>
```

So in your case :

if you want the entire input as a string with quotes you should do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: ' " ' + document.getElementById("email_input") + ' " ' 

});
</script>
```

if you just want the input value as a string (so the email) with quotes you should do :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
test({

  email: ' " ' + document.getElementById("email_input").value + ' " ' 

});
</script>
```

hope I've made myself clear
Feel free to ask if I'm not

have a good one